# UICollectionView Cell Origin - Mosaic like

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have to display some images in my UICollectionView. In my case, I have 3 different types of image (Square, Portrait, landscape). What I did till now to show the different types of items :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height); 
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}
```

The problem that actually the items are displayed like the image bellow: 
[image: What i actually have]

But the result wanted is to show the images like a mosaic as the image : [image: What I want to display]

PS: I've tried some frameworks such as : [RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout) and [MosaicLayout](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout) but it does not work either (same result as mine).

I believe that I am not the first to have this kind of problem to resolve.

Thank you for your contributions in advance.
Regards

Comment: Did you try this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest ?

Comment: I saw the tutorial, but unfortunately (for me)  it was in swift.

Comment: https://medium.com/@cp-satish-v/mosaic-layout-with-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-6e4b668503bf